# Inpaint Skewed/Tilted Text Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm running OCR on a image with python and then getting the coordinates of each word and performing masking and inpainting on it. Here is my current result [image: Result]

[image: TOP]

As you can see, on the top of image, the text is not inpainted correctly. I figured it out by plotting the coordinates of the text with OPENCV as well as manually. I noticed that Opencv only performs cropping in a horizontal or vertical rectangle manner or vertical rectangle like here :

[image: TEXT CROPPED INCORRECTLY]

If I plot the same image using same coordinates on a image-editing tool like paint, I'm getting the correct bounding box i.e., [image: THIS]

I don't want this to happen as it is affecting my results. How do I improve this?

CODE:

```
    textCoordinates = runOcr(img)
    for i in textCoordinates:
        tl[1],br[1],tl[0],br[0]]  = i.coordinates
        smImg = img[tl[1]:br[1],tl[0]:br[0]]
        inpaintedImg = inpaintAlgo(smImg) ## this function detects and creates a mask and inpaints by it.
```

Comment: No, actually, when I open my paint and using the same numbers I try to make a box at the same cordinates, actually the box should have been a bit skewed. But when I put the numbers using cv2.rectangle() then the box is only vertical. This same is happening when I am cropping something as well.

Comment: It is known that opencv doesn't automatically make the rectangle in a tilted way. I want to extract that part of image using coordinates.

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand what you mean, and the image you posted with the yellow background clearly is not from the top image of signls. Post an image of what you get in Paint (which is your desired result) and what you get in openCV to see the difference

Comment: Ok, I see two rectangular images, one is bigger and includes all the text, the other smaller and cuts the text. then in the big image you are drawing 4 lines between 4 coordinate points which surround the text. Is this what you need? draw lines between points? you can check this tutorial on how to draw lines into images https://techtutorialsx.com/2019/12/01/python-opencv-drawing-lines-on-image/

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki No I want to extract that part of image, If I use img[y1:y2,x1:x2] I get result similar to that of first image, but I want the result to be like when I do it manually as the opencv cropping isn't good in making rotated crops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248250/discussion-between-sembei-norimaki-and-arnav-mehta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have 4 points

```
[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4]]
```

you need to calculate ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax as

```
ymin = min(y1,y2,y3,y4)
ymax = max(y1,y2,y3,y4)
xmin = min(x1,x2,x3,x4)
xmax = max(x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

ans then your crop will be

```
img[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax]
```

Comment: I gave it a thought, and yes I am able to understand your approach well. Thanks I'll check and implement this :D

Comment: you can accept the answer if it works for you